# not letting me return boolean value to function

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
bool CheckSpread();

int main()
{
    int x;
    int y;
    bool ok;
    do 
    {

        cout << "Please enter some integers" << endl;
        cin >> x >> y;
        CheckSpread(x, y);
        ok == CheckSpread;
    } 
    while (CheckSpread() == true); 
    {
    cout << "The difference between the two numbers is equal to or greater than 10" << endl;

    }


    return 0;
}
int CheckSpread(int a, int b)
{

    int diff = std::abs(a - b);
    if (diff >= 10)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;


}
```

Trying to make a program that when run the user inputs integers and will be able to continue inputting integers until the difference of the numbers input is greater than or equal to 10. For example if i input

1

2

3

4

14

"the difference between is greater than 10"

However boo leans are tricky for me still and the do while. shouldn't checkspread be returning a true or false to the while statement?

Comment: sorry im really new let me try and fix

Comment: Please learn some basic programming. Typing random code and then asking people why it doesn't work isn't an efficient way to learn.

Comment: @Drewdinie There are *a lot* of strange things in the code. `CheckSpread(x, y)` is useless since its result is never used. `ok == CheckSpread` is just wrong; you're assigning a function to a `bool` variable (but then you never use that variable, so who knows what you're trying to do). (`== true` is superfluous, but not *wrong* per se.) `bool CheckSpread()` and `int CheckSpread(int a, int b)` are different functions. The former is never defined, so the code shouldn't even compile. The block after `while(…);` doesn't do what I think you think it does. You *really* should go back to your book.

Comment: @juanchopanza this is me trying to learn basic programming its very difficult for me sheesh.

Comment: @Drewdinie … And enable more warnings in your compiler and read what the messages say.

Comment: should i just google how to enable more (using visual studio community)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You don't need all of these

```
    CheckSpread(x, y);
    ok == CheckSpread;
} 
while (CheckSpread() == true); 
{
cout << "The difference between the two numbers is equal to or greater than 10" << endl;

}
```

Instead,

```
do 
{
    cout << "Please enter some integers" << endl;
    cin >> x >> y;

    if (!CheckSpread(x, y))
        break;
} 
while (1); 
{
    cout << "The difference between the two numbers is equal to or greater than 10" << endl;
}
```

Comment: I figured it out and it makes much more sense now thank you so much @sean83

Comment: I think you need basic programming before asking the question like other said but to answer you don't have CheckSpread() function and CheckSpread variable also you cannot have same name of function and variable, etc.